# [help]Linking buttons to a new page, Python GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a GUI using tkinter. I searched for solutions on Google but to no avail. How do I link a button to a new page or when I select a file,it will automatically goes to the next page (with the information saved and transferred to the new page?) I am doing a video segmentation app by the way.

P.s. I am a beginner at python and programming. Hopefully there is someone that can share with me a good reference link so that I can learn

Comment: please show what you have tried so far and why its not working ... also may want to change "page" to "screen" unless you are working with a tkinter widget that provides "pages"

Comment: @joran Beasley okay I for that. I am a beginner and just started learning on python. Hopefully someone can link me to a reference page so that I can learn. What do you mean by "screen"? As far as I known,I found one reference but it is using tabs. Mine is more like a setup wizard format.

Comment: so you have tried nothing so far? I would start by "googling python tkinter tutorial" , or even "python tkinter wizard form" if you want easy copy/paste code  ... that should get you started ... then once you hit a roadblock while actually coding come ask us a more specific

Comment: @joran beasley okay sure! By the way,I am doing an app that edits video or audio file. Is it recommended to use a wizard form? Or just a normal gui?

Comment: I think I would start with something simpler ... a wizard is probably fine ... but start small break it into parts etc

Comment: @joran Beasley okay thank you so much. I already did the layout and a browse button. I am just stuck with the next step which is after i select the file,I will go to the next page automatically. (Sorry,I don't have the codes now because I am on my phone right now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to learn Tkinter [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm). I believe your issue could be solved by Tkinter easily.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use few `Frame`'s and `pack/pack_forget` to show/hide frames.

```
import Tkinter as tk

def go_to_first():
    f1.pack()
    f2.pack_forget()

def go_to_second():
    f1.pack_forget()
    f2.pack()

master = tk.Tk()

# first frame - without f1.pack()
f1 = tk.Frame(master)
l1 = tk.Label(f1, text="First Frame")
l1.pack()
b1 = tk.Button(f1, text="Go to Second", command=go_to_second)
b1.pack()

# second frame - without f2.pack()
f2 = tk.Frame(master)
l2 = tk.Label(f2, text="Second Frame")
l2.pack()
b2 = tk.Button(f2, text="Go to First", command=go_to_first)
b2.pack()

# show first frame
f1.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

My sources of knowledge:

[effbot: Tkinterbook #1](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm)
[effbot: Tkinterbook #2](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/)
[TutorialsPoint: Python GUI Programming (Tkinter)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm)
[TkDocs: tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html)
[New Mexico Tech: Tkinter 8.5 reference: a GUI for Python](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html)
[Tk Reference Manual](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tk/)